# ruby scripting: parent output missing after exec

Tags: ruby, bash, process, io-redirection

I have a ruby script that writes some output and then `exec`s a command. The command would like to inherit the parent's file descriptors because it's going to read from `stdin`, transform it somehow and then write the output to `stdout`.

Here is an example

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'hello from parent'
exec 'tr', '[:lower:]', '[:upper:]'
```

If we run this directly in the shell, we see both lines of output

```
$ echo 'hello, world!' | ./example.rb
hello from parent
HELLO, WORLD!
```

However if the `stdout` of the process is being redirected, we lose the output from the parent.

```
$ echo 'hello, world!' | ./example.rb | cat
HELLO, WORLD!
```

Why is this? What's the difference between the first case and the second?

Also, if we change the `exec` to `system` in the ruby script, then both lines are printed to the terminal. What causes this difference in behaviour?

---

Just for the sake of comparison, a roughly equivalent bash script doesn't seem to exhibit the same behaviour:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello from parent'
exec 'tr' '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

We get the output from the parent as well as the child.

```
$ echo 'hello, world!' | ./example.sh | cat
hello from parent
HELLO, WORLD!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Ruby does not flush the stdout before it `exec`s another program. You can flush stdout explicitly.

```
[STEP 105] # cat example.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'hello from parent'
$stdout.flush
exec 'tr', '[:lower:]', '[:upper:]'
[STEP 106] # echo 'hello, world!' | ./example.rb | cat
hello from parent
HELLO, WORLD!
[STEP 107] #
```

Comment: That does the trick. I suppose the buffering is configured differently when outputting to a TTY as opposed to a file or a pipe. Thanks!

Comment: outputting to stdout which is a tty is usually line buffered so it works fine without `| cat`. stderr is usually unbuffered. (NOTE: this applies when using `FILE *` related APIs. syscalls like `read(2)`, `write(2)` are never buffered.)